# How to determine audio full LCID language identifier from a video file?

Tags: audio, tracks

I've successfully created a video with 3 language audio tracks (English, French, Spanish). When playing back in a video player that recognizes the languages, I can correctly switch between these tracks.

For each language, there is an LCID (Language Code Identifier) embedded in the video file. I know they're there, but can't see the detailed LCID. The format should be similar to this: "es-MX" for Spanish-Mexico. But I only know the first part ("es" in this case) and can't confirm the second part ("MX").

I have both .mov and .wmv versions of the video file. Is there some way to examine the video files and see the full LCID? I.E, I'd like to be able to see "en-US", "fr-FR" and "es-MX" or whatever they are set to.

Thanks ... John

Comment: mediainfo https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo maybe ?

Comment: @audionuma - Thanks; that's a cool tool! I was able to see most of the information I was looking for by using it.